# Apache Spark 2.0 - date_add function

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I have a simple schema with a date and an int. I want to use date_add to add the int to the date.

```
scala> val ds1 = spark.read.option("inferSchema",true).csv("samp.csv")

ds1.printSchema();

root
 |-- _c0: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: integer (nullable = true)
```

I cannot get the first param to date_add work...please help!

```
scala> val ds2 = ds1.map ( x => date_add(x.getAs[timestamp]("_c0"),  x.getAs[Int]("_c1")))
<console>:28: error: not found: type timestamp

scala> val ds2 = ds1.map ( x => date_add(x.getAs[Column]("_c0"), x.getAs[Int] ("_c1")))
<console>:28: error: not found: type Column
```

Answer (score 1):

`date_add` is not your immediate problem... `not found: type {timestamp, Column}`

I'm not sure how you expect `x.getAs[timestamp]` to work, honestly, but for the other, you need an import.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_add
```

Now try

```
val ds2 = ds1.map { x => 
    date_add(ds1("_c0"), x.getAs[Int] ("_c1"))
}
```

(Though, you should ideally not be using `Dataset.map`)

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah i was so frustrated, i was trying everythingscala> val ds2 = ds1.map ( x => date_add(ds1.col("_c0"), x.getAs[Int]("_c1")))
<console>:30: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
       val ds2 = ds1.map ( x => date_add(ds1.col("_c0"), x.getAs[Int]("_c1")))
                         ^

Comment: And when i use foreach i get a null pointer exception
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2286)
  at 
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreach(Dataset.scala:2285)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolve(Dataset.scala:217)

Comment: New to spark and all this so clueless how to proceed. my ds has values.
+--------------------+---+
|                 _c0|_c1|
+--------------------+---+
|2017-01-01 00:00:...| 10|
|2017-02-01 00:00:...| 28|
+--------------------+---+

Comment: Like I said, ideally not be using Dataset.map (especially not foreach). You could try `ds1.col("_c1").as[Int]`, or something like that

Comment: The `col(String name)` function is correct. The second parameter needs to be an integer, not a column. Or, you could try raw SQL, not mess with the dataset methods